# Prove that there is no isometry from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: geometry

How should I start of? I know if $T$ is an isometry then $T=A \vec x+\vec b$ where A is orthogonal matrix and $\vec b$ is a column vector. If I can prove that there is no orthogonal matrix from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ then will it suffice?(which I don't think is true?)
(Also my understanding of isometries is quite basic, I know isometries preserve distance and dot product)

Comment: No, what you say you know about isometries is a theorem for $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a tetrahedron in $\mathbb R^3$. Its vertices are four points equidistant from each other.

An isometry with $\mathbb R^2$ would create such a set in $\mathbb R^2$, but this is clearly impossible.

One way to see is that since distinct circles in $\mathbb R^2$ only intersect in at most two locations. If you pick two points $A,B$ distance $d$ apart, and you want to find two more points distance $d$ away from $A,B$, then you *must* select the intersections $C,D$ of circles radius $d$ around $A,B$. But unfortunately, $C$ and $D$ are necessarily $d\sqrt{3}$ apart, not $d$!

Comment: While this is a neat idea, I'm having trouble linking number of intersections of circles with the (non-)existence of 4 points equidistant from each other. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Pick two points $A,B$ distance $d$ apart and draw a circle of radius $d$ around both.   Now you need two more points $C,D$ distance $d$ from these points. Happily, there are exactly two candidates at the intersections of the circles. But too bad for you, $C$ and $D$ are distance $d\sqrt{3}$ from each other :(

Comment: I know that, but don't you think that $CD = 2\sqrt{3}d$ is also the key idea and should be included in the argument?

Comment: @QuangHoang Although I didn't think it was really necessary to spell it out, I did now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just prove that an isometry that fixes the origin preserves linear independence. And that $T$ is an isometry if and only if $A$ is.

Comment: The user's notion of an isometry *doesn't* preserve linear independence, though. For instance, the isometry $T(x)=x+v$ for a fixed $v\neq 0$ will send the linearly independent set $\{-v\}$ to $\{0\}$.  I know what you're getting at is true for the isometries preserving the origin, though.  I guess it can be saved by rephrasing.

Comment: Good point. Done.